# Изменение значения итерации в цикле по нажатию мыши на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Имеется цикл, выводящий числа с интервалом. Необходимо по нажатию на кнопку изменить текущее значение итерации на заданную величину. Например – сбросить обратно до 17.

```js
let mainBlock = document.querySelector('#outputBlock');
let changeButton = document.querySelector('#changeIterator');

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
 setTimeout(function(i) {
  mainBlock.innerHTML = i;
 }, i * 170, i);
}
```

```css
#outputBlock {margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="outputBlock"></div>
<button id="changeIterator">Изменить на 17</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let mainBlock = document.querySelector('#outputBlock');
let changeButton = document.querySelector('#changeIterator');
let timeoutCounter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  mainBlock.innerHTML = timeoutCounter++;
 }, i * 170);
}
```

```css
#outputBlock {margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="outputBlock"></div>
<button id="changeIterator" onclick="timeoutCounter=timeoutCounter+17;">Изменить на 17</button>
```

Учтите, что Вы в плотном цикле заказываете 101 таймаут. Цикл отработал до конца (но ни один из них еще не выполнился), а **потом** они начинают выстреливать.

```js
let mainBlock = document.querySelector('#outputBlock');
let changeButton = document.querySelector('#changeIterator');
let timeoutCounter = 0;

function orderTimeout() {
  if (timeoutCounter <= 100) {
    mainBlock.innerHTML = timeoutCounter++;
    setTimeout(orderTimeout, 170);
  }
}
orderTimeout();
```

```css
#outputBlock {margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="outputBlock"></div>
<button id="changeIterator" onclick="timeoutCounter=17;">Изменить на 17</button>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно изменить само значение i, а не увеличить его на указанную величину.

Comment: @Vedenin а пожалуйста!

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо я очень плохо объясняю.Итерация дошла до 75, в этот момент я нажимаю на кнопку – итерация равна 17 и снова увеличивается (18, 19...).

Comment: @Vedenin а пожалуйста!

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Comment: @Vedenin Пожалуйста. Хочу отметить качественное оформление вопроса. Успехов в программировании!